# Continuity of a multivariable function at origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)= \frac{x^2y}{\sqrt{x^6+2y^2}}$ when $ (x,y)\neq (0,0)$, $f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise. The hint says that we can prove discontinuity at $0$ by considering the sequence $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^3})$. Even if we take this sequence, the function on this sequence converges to $0$ as $n$ becomes large. So we do not get any contradiction. $f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n^3})$ is actually $\frac {1}{\sqrt{3}n^2}$ which converges to $0$. How can we prove the discontinuity at the origin?

Comment: @Luchoming You may want to think about the value of that fraction when $n$ is $1000$, say.

Comment: The hint is wrong; the function can be extended continuously to the origin, with $f(0,0)=0$, because you can write $f(x, y) =x^2\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^6+2y^2}}$, and the fraction is bounded by $1$.

Comment: Seems that the limit is $0$

Comment: Thanks to all, this was pestering me for quite a while. I tried all known techniques for proving discontinuity but failed. I should have observed that the function is continuous.

Comment: When $|x| < 1,$ then $x^2 > x^6,$ so $x^6 + 2y^2 \geq x^2 + y^2,$ and therefore $f(x,y) \leq x^2 |y| / \|(x,y)\| \leq x^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit at the origin is $0$, in fact:

$$\left| \frac{x^2y}{\sqrt{x^6+2y^2}}-0\right|\leq  \frac{x^2|y|}{\sqrt{x^6+y^2}}\leq  \frac{x^2|y|}{\sqrt{y^2}}=x^2$$
Since $g(x)=x^2$ is positive and approaches $0$ as $x\to 0$, you can conclude that the limit is $0$.